# Importxml using xpath returns #N/A error with imported contents is empty"

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am trying to scrape texts using importxml / xpath. But it returns #N/A and "Imported content is empty".

I am trying to scrape "223 3563 ROSS DRIVE" on the top. (In fact, I will try to scrape all the information in the page later.)

I have tried with these two codes from GoogleSheet, but no success.

Please help me resolve this.

```
=index(IMPORTXML("https://bcres.paragonrels.com/publink/default.aspx?GUID=11a3e139-7499-4271-813a-fe2f70ffd304&Report=Yes","//div[@class='mls21']"),1,1)

=index(IMPORTXML("https://bcres.paragonrels.com/publink/default.aspx?GUID=11a3e139-7499-4271-813a-fe2f70ffd304&Report=Yes","//*[@id='divHtmlReport']/div/div[154]"),1,1)
```

Comment: I've edited the word 'scrap' (which means you want to completely throw away) to be the word 'scape' (which means you like search and retrieve certain data).

Answer (score 0):

IMPORT function can’t extract from content that loads with JavaScript. You can check this article: https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/import-social-media-statistics/#notWorking

You can confirm that the website is JavaScript controlled by clicking on the ‘Lock’ icon beside the browser’s address bar, select ‘Site settings’ and set JavaScript to ‘Block’. Reload the page and if you don’t see the data you’re trying to extract, then you will not be able to get it with IMPORT functions.

An alternative to do it through Google Sheets would be to look for a Sheets Add-on that may work with JavaScript content.